# Reliable way to send file over internet

Tags: file, tcp, udp, ip, transfer

First of all: I'm not absolutely certain that this is the right place to ask, but I think the question fits here better then on superuser or serverfault, since it is a question from a programmer's perspective: I figured more programmers might have had the same question (although I couldn't find this specific question!).

I would like to have a feature in my program which allows users to send files to a 'friend'. You can find friends via an username: this all goes via a server which can provide the IP-adress of a friend.
I wanted to use a tcp connection to send the file. This becomes difficult, however, when one (or both) of the parties is behind a NAT. What is the best way to solve this? I heard that it's possible to send stuff via a server, but I'd rather send everything directly, to prevent server overhead.

I heard about a technique called hole punching, but also that it's pretty complex to implement and not 100% reliable. I could use UDP and implement some scheme to improve the reliability, but this seems a bit complex to me. I know skype, bittorrent and a whole lot of other programs do similiar things (but I don't know about the specifics, which protocol they use, if they use hole punching etc.).

I looked into FTP a bit, until I realised that this is just a protocol using TCP, so I should use TCP hole punching in order to let this work... Anyway, I hope someone can give me some advice on this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to make data pass through a server, I'm not aware of other methods other than [TCP Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) or simple [Port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) of a previously choosen port.

Comment: Too bad. Gonna try that then. Thanks@